# How to automatically add an autoscaled EC2 instance to a Security Group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-api-tools

I want to set up my AWS to autoscale EC2 instances (Windows Server 2012). The catch is that they need to have their IP addresses added to a Security Group so they can communicate with another EC2.

1. Is there a way that AWS can handle this automatically through its autoscaling feature? (The closest I could find was to assign an IAM role to the new instances, but I don't I can add an IAM role to a Security Group, I can only add IP addresses.)
2. The way I am currently looking into is to use the AWS CLI (command line) as a startup script.

   ```
   ec2-authorize mySecurityGroup -p 1433 -s xx.xx.xx.xx/32
   ```

But how do I get the public IP of the current instance? Is there a AWS CLI command to get this? I'd rather not depend on an external website like "curl echoip.com". I heard about ec2-metadata, but I don't think that works for Windows, and I'd prefer not to use another third party software.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't add rule to authorize all instances in a given security group? Are you trying to set up access across regions?

Comment: I'm open to that option. I'm staying with the same region. I just don't know how to do it (I'm pretty new to AWS EC2). I thought I can only add IP addresses to a security group.

Comment: It works similar to adding an ip, instead you would specify your security group id (starts with sg-XXXXXX).

Comment: I tried that, but the issue still comes back to: how do I automatically add the new instance to that security group? For example: let's say I have "EC2-DB" that has security group "SG-DB" to restrict access. I autoscale "EC2-Web1" and assign it security group "SG-Web". Even if I add "SG-Web" under "SG-DB", that doesn't give EC2-Web1 access to EC2-DB, because EC2-Web1 doesn't belong to SG-Web.

Comment: Arg, finally figured out the issue. When you use a security group (as opposed to IP address) in a rule, there is a quirk that you cannot use the Public IP to reference that instance. I had been referencing the instance with Public IP (since it worked with IP address security rules), and that's what threw me off the whole time. They should have documented this quirk better!

Comment: @wisbucky you can always use the public hostname. it will resolve to the private IP when resolved from within the same AWS region.

Comment: @wisbucky Thank you for posting that !  Hard to believe how poorly documented that is. I Burned significant time trying to figure out why the auto scale security group wasn't working as documented.

Comment: @muhqu using the public DNS can be helpful . thanks for that. Strange that the public DNS hostname routs as expected but not public IP. Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a security group called web. For the sake of an example, lets say the id of that group is: sg-7aa91911

Create a security group called db.
Add a new rule to the db security group for port 1433 with the source of sg-7aa91911

Create an Autoscaling launch configuration and set the SecurityGroups to sg-7aa91911 and any other configuration you need.

Create Autoscaling group with that launch configuration.

I wrote up a quick CloudFormation template to do this task. You should be able to just run it and it will create an Autoscaling group with the connected security groups. It'll also create a blank instance where you can store your db.

If you prefer not to use a CloudFormation template, just look at where the security groups are defined. It shows how the 2 security groups are to be connected

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

  "Description" : "test tempalte",

  "Parameters" : {
    "KeyName" : {
      "Description" : "Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance",
      "Type" : "String"
    }
  },

  "Mappings" : {
    "RegionMap" : {
      "us-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "ami-7f418316" },
      "us-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "ami-951945d0" },
      "us-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "ami-16fd7026" },
      "eu-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "ami-24506250" },
      "sa-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "ami-3e3be423" },
      "ap-southeast-1" : { "AMI" : "ami-74dda626" },
      "ap-northeast-1" : { "AMI" : "ami-dcfa4edd" }
    }
  },

  "Resources" : {
    "WebServerGroup" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "AvailabilityZones" : { "Fn::GetAZs" : "" },
        "LaunchConfigurationName" : { "Ref" : "LaunchConfig" },
        "MinSize" : "1",
        "MaxSize" : "10",
        "DesiredCapacity" : "1"
      }
    },

    "LaunchConfig" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
      "Properties" : {
        "InstanceType" : "m1.small",
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "websg"} ],
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]}
      }
    },
    "Ec2Instance" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties" : {
        "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
        "ImageId" : { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "RegionMap", { "Ref" : "AWS::Region" }, "AMI" ]},
        "UserData" : { "Fn::Base64" : "80" }
      }
    },

    "websg" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Enable SSH and access, 8080, and 80",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "8080", "ToPort" : "8080", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"},
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"},
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"}
        ]
      }
    },
    "dbsg" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
      "Properties" : {
        "GroupDescription" : "Port opened only to security group",
        "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
          {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "1433", "ToPort" : "1433", "SourceSecurityGroupName" : {"Ref" : "websg"}
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed example. In the end, my biggest problem was that I trying to connect to the "DB" using its Public IP. I finally realized that there is a quirk when you use security group rule, you either have to use Public DNS or Private DNS/IP.